# is a 'field' but used like a 'type' (it is really a type)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I am getting **expectedExceptionType is a 'field' but used like a 'type'** error from the *if (exception is expectedExceptionType)* line. However as you can see it **is** a Type. What is the problem here?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with .NET 4.5

```
public sealed class ExpectedInnerException : ExpectedExceptionBaseAttribute 
{
    private Type expectedExceptionType;
    private string expectedExceptionMessage;

    public ExpectedInnerException(Type expectedExceptionType, string expectedExceptionMessage)
    {
        this.expectedExceptionType = expectedExceptionType;
        this.expectedExceptionMessage = expectedExceptionMessage;
    }

    protected override void Verify(Exception exception)
    {
        if (exception is expectedExceptionType)
        {

        }
        //Some other code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is` operator expects a type expression, not a variable/field with `System.Type` type.

The compatible solution:

```
protected override void Verify(Exception exception)
{
    if (expectedExceptionType.IsAssignableFrom(exception.GetType()))
    {

    }
    //Some other code
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`expectedExceptionType` is an instance of the type `Type`, not a compile-time-type in itself. Thus write this instead:

```
protected override void Verify(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception.GetType() == expectedExceptionType)
    {

    }
    //Some other code
}
```

EDIT: If your type is a subclass from that one reflected by `expectedExceptionType` you can check for [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (exception.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(expectedExceptionType.GetType()))
```

Comment: In this case if exception is a subclass of expectedExceptionType, it will return false. That's way I wanted to use "is"

Comment: @NuriTasdemir Yes, you´re right, I updated the answer.

Comment: Your update a bit wierd. `IOException` is not assignable from `Exception` for instance

Comment: So you should turn it around since the `expectedExceptionType` can be he higher one.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Yeap, finally noticed, thanks for the hint however :)

Answer (score 2):

[HimBromBeere told you the reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36302568/993547), but not the best way to solve this, since checking on the type directly won't work with interfaces and derived instances.

This code does:

```
protected override void Verify(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(expectedExceptionType))
    {

    }
    //Some other code
}
```

Comment: you were faster than me